# RecordEditForm: Reset inputfield after successful submit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I have a Lightning RecordEditForm on a page that I'd like use multiple times.  After a successful submit I want to clear the user's entries to allow the form to be reused.  I have been unsuccessful at clearing RecordEditForm InputField component values in the onsuccess callback of the form.

Here is what I am trying:

**Component**

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="createAccount"
                            objectApiName="Account"
                            onsuccess="{!c.saveComplete}">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"
                            aura:id="accountNameField" />
    <lightning:button aura:id="submit"
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        label="Create Account"
                        class="slds-m-top_medium" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

**Controller**

```
saveComplete: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.getAccountList(component);

    // Grab inputField needing to be reset.  Attempt to change it.
    var cmp = component.find("accountNameField");
    console.log("current value: " + cmp.get("v.value"));    // Display current value

    cmp.set("v.value", "a new value");                      // Change it (hopefully)

    console.log("new value: " + cmp.get("v.value"));        // Display updated value
},
```

**Console output**

```
current value: cccc
new value: cccc
```

The user's inputed value does not change on the screen nor in the inputfield component attribute.

What is the proper way to reset a recordeditform inputfield after a submit completes?

Comment: Probably destroying the component and then dynamically creating it.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, you're right, that works.  It's not a technique I'd used before.  And, I hate it.  I really want my xml in the .cmp file and the business logic in the .js, and the two not mixing.   That said, if someone else doesn't post a better solution, I'll share this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you can add your lightning:recordEditForm inside the aura:if and reset the flag variable used in aura:if in insaveComplete() method .This will refresh the form.

Comment: Thank you Rohan.  This worked and was easier than recreating the form in javascript (per comment in original question).

Comment: @Rohan -- Would you mind giving an example?  I think you're saying the answer is to wrap the whole recordEditForm inside an aura:if, and then change the value of the variable used in the isTrue value. This does work for me the first time -- the form is cleared -- but after that, I can't address the form.  Example: cmp.find('myRecordEditForm').submit() doesn't work because myRecordEditForm isn't found.