# lightning:inputField value not overriding for lookup field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield

We have a Lightning Component with some of this:

```
<aura:attribute name="editRecordId" type="string"/>
<aura:attribute name="serviceId" type="string"/>

<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="MyObject__c" recordId="{!v.editRecordId}">
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Service__c" value="{!v.serviceId}"/>
    <!--That ^ is a lookup field-->
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

So we have a couple of `aura:attributes`. One to decide if (and which record) we are editing (less relevant for this question), and one to allow the input of a lookup field to come from somewhere else.
Controller side we have this:

```
handleRecordSelected: function(component, event, helper){
    var recordId = event.getParam("recordId");
    if (recordId){
        component.set("v.serviceId", recordId);
    }
},
```

So what that does is set the value of `serviceId` to allow the lookup field `Service__c` to get a value from somewhere else (where is not relevant for this question).
That works.

It **doesn't** work if there was previously a value in the `Service__c` field, if the user chose it (using the standard Salesforce interface). If the user is editing and it had a value in that field that came from the DB, then the `serviceId` value overrides.
The [specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification) for `lightning:inputField` specifically shows that the `value` attribute overrides the existing values.
So to reiterate: In most conditions this works. It only doesn't work if the user selects a value in the field (you know, click the lookup field, start typing, select one of the results that pop up) and then uses a different interface (one that calls `handleRecordSelected`) to set the value.
In that case it retains the value that the user selected in the lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround, **NOT** a solution, based on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227726/recordeditform-reset-inputfield-after-successful-submit).

I surrounded my `<lightning:inputField fieldName="Service__c" value="{!v.serviceId}"/>` with `aura:if` and reset it before a different record Id is forthcoming.
So I'm basically removing the `inputField` from the DOM and when it is added back it has no value and then my code can set its value.

Comment: I'm having this same problem of not being able to override a value in a lightning:inputField lookup for an existing record with a value in that field, and I'm trying to override the value.  I've tried surrounding just the field with aura:if and only render it when my overridden value is set, and also surrounding the entire form in aura:if, but neither works.  No matter what I do, the inputField is always shown with the existing value, never my overridden value.